# check a string that contain only letter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, expression

why this code accept a null value ???

```
protected bool ValidateOnlyLetter(String s)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return false;
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, "[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]") && !Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[A-Za-z ]+$")) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

It's should accept only letter english or arabic but its accept empty string

when I call the function :

```
if (!ValidateOnlyLetter(name.Text)) err1.Text = MessageNotification.Notify("Error");
```

Comment: It's returning `false` for input = `""`

Comment: If the string truly is empty, your function should return false.  However, if it has whitespace in it then `String.IsNullOrEmpty` will return false.  You can try using [`String.IsNullOrWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if that's the  case.

Comment: Side note: you can merge your character classes, e.g. `[a-c]|[x-z]` is the same as `[a-cx-z]`.